# PPTX в HTML и вывод в WebView

Tags: java, android, html, webview

Здравствуйте, проблема заключается в следующем, у меня есть презентация, и я её конвертирую в HTML, чтобы потом вывести её через WebView, но проблема с масштабированием, я хочу чтобы html страничка автоматически подгонялась под экран, пробовал использовать мета тег viewport и с помощью скрипта подбирать разные maximum-scale для разных экранов, но без результата, пробовал метод setInitialScale() , тоже безрезультатно, если не совсем понятно, то например есть электронная книга и когда мы ее запускаем с помощью ридера и изменяем размер ридера, то книга меняет свои размеры и при этом все пропорционально.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил проблему так:

```
<meta name="viewport" id="viewport" content="width=1024">


</head>
<body id="bld" style="margin:0;">

<script type="text/javascript">
var viewPortWidth = 1100;
function setViewport() {
if ((navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("android")!=-1)) {
    var wW0 = window.screen.width;
    var scale = wW0/viewPortWidth;
    var vPort = "width="+viewPortWidth+", maximum-scale="+scale+", minimum-scale="+scale+", initial-scale="+scale+", user-scalable=yes";
    document.getElementById("viewport").setAttribute("content", vPort);
}
}
setViewport();
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webView.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
webView.setInitialScale(1);
```